# Error compiling Java from command line

Tags: java, hadoop

I am doing a Friend Suggester application in Java using Hadoop 2.7.2 (latest atm) and I just finished the code. I want to compile the `.java` file and create the `.class` files but when I run the command

```
javac -d "/home/gramanas/" -cp "/srv/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.2.jar:/srv/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.2.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64" FriendSuggest.java
```

I get the following error:

```
FriendSuggest.java:63: error: 
error while writing FriendMapper: /home/gramanas/FriendSuggest$FriendMapper.class
    public static class FriendMapper
                  ^
```

I don't think it has something to do with the code since it compiles normally in IDEA. I want to compile it from command line but I can't get it to work.

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Additional Info:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Hadoop 2.7.2 pseudo distributed mode
- java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64

Comment: Are you sure you have writing permissions in the path where the code is? Maybe try to move it elsewhere where you are sure.

Comment: @LorisSecuro I feel stupid. But I was expecting a warning having to do with permission if that was the case. I used sudo and it compiled successfully.

Comment: In the future, please try to write a more informative question title, one that succinctly tells us exactly what your problem is, not a general complaint or plight.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to build from the command line? You can use Maven to build a JAR file for Hadoop to run

Comment: @cricket_007I follow https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Example:_WordCount_v1.0 and they use command line tools to build the jar. Plus i have no idea what maven is! I will learn it but not till i really need it :D

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You have a point. I will try to be more specific next time. Do you have a suggestion for this question's title?

Comment: Don't use sudo unless you really need to.  If you end up with files owned by root, you will see errors exactly like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That type of error might be caused by not having writing permissions on the path you are executing the compilation.

You should try to compile where/when you are sure to have such permissions.